# QGIS 3.4. Saving Layer Status (ON/OFF) for printing different Layouts

Tags: qgis, layers, layouts, mapping

if i have a project with a lot layers (20-30) and i want to print different map layouts is there a possibility to save different status of which layer is on or off?
So for example:

Map Layout 1:
Layer 1:ON
Layer 2:Off
Layer 3:Off

Map Layout 2:
Layer 1:Off
Layer 2:On
layer 3:On

My Problem is, when i have to change something after 2 months not working on the project and plot the map layouts again, i dont remember which layer to switch on/off in which map layout...

In Autocad you can use the "layer status save"function to save different states of layer on/off for different map layouts...

Or is there a other possible workaround for that question? (i am still a beginner)

Comment: Have you had a look at `map themes´ and how they work?

Comment: Thank you very, very much for your help! Both workarounds are very helpful for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each print layout, select the map. In the Item Properties panel, check the box that says "lock layers."

[image]

This will lock the combination of layers that are currently on or off for this map item.

If you like, you can use the expression builder to define a list of layers for that map. This option allows you to add or remove layers from a map without recreating the layer setup in the main map canvas.

Per Erik's suggestion,  you may want to look into "map themes" - they allow you to pre-define a set of layers that you can then choose from a dropdown in the map properties in the print layout.

Comment: Thank you very, very much for your help! Both workarounds are very helpful for me! Thanks!